# Is there a way to print a desired x and y value directly from a graph using arrays in python? I also need to have the x axis at y = 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

[Current plot with markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6q83.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as mth

x = np.array([0.0012,0.0006,0.0004,0.0003,0.00024,0.0002])

y = np.array([-160,-35,-4.2,9.0,16.9,21.3])

plt.xlabel('1/RT')

plt.ylabel('B(T)')

plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', markersize = 10)

plt.savefig("Van der Waals.pdf", dpi = 600)
```

This is the code I have so far, I need to print a desired x value and a y intercept so they can be used later to find the coefficients of the van der Waal equation for nitrogen specifically. I also need to add a line at y = 0 so my x axis isnt at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0.0012, 0.0006, 0.0004, 0.0003, 0.00024, 0.0002])
y = np.array([-160, -35, -4.2, 9.0, 16.9, 21.3])
plt.xlabel('1/RT')
plt.ylabel('B(T)')
plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', markersize=10)

#Task 1
# Define the desired point
desired_x = 0.0002
desired_y = np.interp(desired_x, x, y)

# Plot the desired point
plt.scatter(desired_x, desired_y, color="red")

# Annotate the desired point with its coordinates
plt.annotate(f'({desired_x:.4f}, {desired_y:.2f})', xy=(desired_x, desired_y),
             xytext=(desired_x + 0.00005, desired_y + 5),
             arrowprops=dict(facecolor="black", arrowstyle='->'))


#Task 2
# Add a line at y = 0 (I assumed this is what you wanted)
plt.axhline(0, color="black", linestyle='--')  


plt.savefig("Van_der_Waals.pdf", dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this worksout for you

Comment: As `x` is in descending order, you need to reverse both `x` and `y` in the call to `np.interp`: `desired_y = np.interp(desired_x, x[::-1], y[::-1])`

Comment: See also [How do you make the x-axis pass through (0,0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016339/how-do-you-make-the-x-axis-pass-through-0-0-with-matplotlib-in-python) for an alternative way to set the x-axis at y=0.